# Python printing the word

Tags: python

If any one can help me with Python code:
If I input a letter, How can I print all the words start with that word?

Answer (score 2):

```
print [word for word in words if word.startswith(letter)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, e.g.:

```
words = ["zwei", "peanuts", "were", "walking", "down", "the", "strasse"]
letter = "w"
output = [x for x in words if x[0] == letter]
```

The contents of `output` will be:

```
['were', 'walking']
```

Some notes:

- If the code needs to be *fast* you should put the wordlist in some kind of tree.
- If you need more flexibility, you should build a regular expression for matching